# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import requests
from time import sleep


from telebot import apihelper


# apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5://198.50.217.202:1080'}

# apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://10.10.1.10:3128'}

# #xxx - ip, yyyy - port

token = ''

URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/"

def get_updates():
    url = URL + 'getupdates'
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r)





def main():
    get_updates()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Выдаёт ошибку(Токен скрыт мною)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 301, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x038E7450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<token>/getupdates (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x038E7450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/TelegramBot/bot1.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/TelegramBot/bot1.py", line 28, in main
    get_updates()
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/TelegramBot/bot1.py", line 20, in get_updates
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<token>/getupdates (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x038E7450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))
```

Comment: Пытался и c proxy ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

token = ''

URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/"

proxies = {
    'https': 'socks5://198.50.217.202:1080'
}


def get_updates():
    url = URL + 'getupdates'
    r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, ).text
    print(r)


def main():
    get_updates()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```